# Test Application Data in "Test" action of project's scheme

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, tdd

I am developing using TDD approach. When digging through project's scheme I've noticed the "Test Application Data" parameter for Test suites/cases.

What is it? What are it's advantages over absence of it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setting allows you to associate data from a device in a certain state with a test target. After using your app on a device or simulator, you can copy the data that the app saved. This is useful if your application needs to run tests that rely on the application already having saved data.

There are a few entries in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/080-Manage_Your_Devices/manage_devices.html) about this. If you find-on-page "Download Your Application’s Data for Analysis" there are instructions on how to copy the data from a device to your development machine.